# Radix UI Theme dark mode not being applied

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, user-interface, radix-ui

I'm trying to create an app using Radix UI. The dark mode should be enabled by setting `appearance="dark"` but all the nested components such as Box and Card stay light.

The accent color prop works fine as well as other props, the only issue seems to be with dark mode.

This is the code.

```js
import { Grid, Theme } from '@radix-ui/themes';
import '@radix-ui/themes/styles.css';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <Theme appearance="dark" accentColor="ruby" radius="large">
      <Grid columns="1" rows="2" align="center">
        <FirstComponent />
        <SecondComponent />
      </Grid>
    </Theme>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't work for me either. What you are doing should work according to the RadixUI [Dark Mode Docs](https://www.radix-ui.com/themes/docs/theme/dark-mode). There are several [open issues related to dark mode not working](https://github.com/radix-ui/themes/issues?q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20dark) on their Github page. Radix Themes just released 2.0.0, but I have verified that this is also broken on 1.1.2. I don't currently have a work-around, but if I find one I'll update my answer.

**Edit:** One of the Github issues mentions turning dark mode on permanently by adding the `dark` class to the `<body>` element: `<body class="dark">`. You could toggle this class on and off using vanilla JS (or a JS library like React), though I'd characterize this as a hack.

Comment: Following the same path i found this [issue](https://github.com/radix-ui/themes/issues/22) and i solved mine by adding the class dark-theme to my HTML tag like this `<html lang="en" class="dark-theme">` however i agree with you, this is more a hack than a solution

Answer (score 0):

A solution I just came up with was having a function that added or removed the class "dark" from the HTML body. Add the below function to a onClick event and  this should solve your problem.

```
const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState<boolean>(false);

const toggleDarkMode = () => {
  setDarkMode(!darkMode);
      if (darkMode) {
        document.body.classList.remove("dark");
       } else {
        document.body.classList.add("dark");
     }
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in index.html file, it has worked for me:

```
<html lang="en" class="dark-theme">
```

Then `appearance="light"` or `appearance="dark"` will work. Also you can switch from one to another.

Answer (score -1):

instead of  `appearance="dark"`, use `appearance="inherit"`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).